# Undo functionality is not working for br tag in Rich Text Editor in CQ

Tags: html, line-breaks, aem, rich-text-editor, undo-redo

We have customized a button which add "**br**" tag at the cursor position of Rich Text Editor in CQ

We are achieving this by creating element by using `Document.createElement("br")` and then appending this element as child node of a parent node.

Now, whenever we are adding this "**br**" (by clicking on button) then the undo functionality doesn't work as expected. 
If we do not append "**br**" tag, then everything is working fine.

I think issue is using document.createElement for creating our tag, since createElement creates an element with opening and closing tag while "**br**" is a empty tag.

Is it possible to overcome this issue? Kindly provide suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you needn't provide any custom button to add a `<br>` tag at the current position.

By default you can use `Shift + Enter` in the editor to provide a line break (adds a `<br>` at the current location of the cursor). This doesnt affect the undo or redo operations.

Note: Using only `Enter` key adds a new paragraph. Using `Shift+Enter` adds line break.

Comment: but may u tell me how can i correct undo functionality since its a business requirement to add a Line Break button.